# Second prototype of an anonymous and named function

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

please can someone explain why b.prototype.prototype undefined (not "Object {}") ?

```
a = function(){}
function b(){}

console.log(a.prototype)                        //Object {} 
console.log(b.prototype)                        //b {}
console.log(a.prototype.prototype)              //undefined 
console.log(b.prototype.prototype)              //undefined
```

a > Object{} > undefined    - ok

b > b{} > ???

Answer (score 1):

Mainly, you seem to be confused by the fact the prototype of `b` seems to be `b` again - which it isn't. Both prototypes are objects and therefore do not have a prototype on their own. The implementation of the "toString()" method (or whatever the specific console you're using utilizes to display this object) of the constructed prototype is just implementation specific and in this case, it includes the function name (if there is one) in the output. You might get a different output in a different browser, e.g., the IE.

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined because you have not assigned anything to the property `prototype` neither have you created it.

```
a.prototype.prototype=a.prototype;
console.log(a.prototype.prototype)//{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would `b.prototype.prototype` be defined?

```
var a = function () {};

a.prototype; // {}

function b () {}

b.prototype; // {}
```

Neither prototype has a property called prototype...
As such, asking for a nonextant property of an object results in `undefined`.

The fact that the console is calling `b.prototype` `"b{}"` doesn't change anything. It's just saying that it's the prototype object of the named-funciton `b`, rather than an anonymous function, like the one assigned to `a`.

It's still an empty object, without a prototype.

Comment: you can define as you desire.

a.prototype.prototype=function(){
    console.log('hi')
    return a.prototype;
}

a().prototype()
//hi

Comment: @spaceman12 of course you can. The point is that he's logging the value. And the console is suggesting that instead of `Object {}` it's `b {}`, ergo, what should the prototype of `b.prototype` be, if you immediately log `b.prototype.prototype;` without assigning anything. Or, what should `instance_of_b.__proto__.__proto__;` point to...  ...or, in actuality, given the code at hand: `instance_of_b.__proto__.prototype;` And the answer to all of these is a resounding `undefined`.